# Add product to cart using code in Craft Commerce plugin

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

I want to add a specific product to a cart using its ID. I have created a module which runs on `Order::EVENT_BEFORE_ADD_LINE_ITEM` event. Here I am able to capture the current cart using the below code

```
$cart = craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getCarts()->getCart();
```

I can also get a Product using the below code

```
$product = \craft\commerce\elements\Product::find()->id([123]); // here 123 is product id
```

But I am not sure how to add this product to the existing cart using a code.

Comment: I don't have a ready to use solution but you can look into the [`craft\commerce\models\LineItem` model](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-models-lineitem.html) and the [`craft\commerce\services\LineItems::createLineItem()` method](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-services-lineitems.html#method-createlineitem).
The cart is an `Order` instance and contains a collection of `LineItem`s. Each `LineItem` has a `Purchasable` id and `Product` implements `Purchasable`.

Answer (score 2):

In Twig, you can do something like this to add purchasable id (n.b. not product id) - `123` to a cart:

```
{% set cart = craft.commerce.carts.cart(true) %}
{% set lineItem = craft.commerce.lineitems.createLineItem(cart.id, 123, {"note":"Test note"}, 2, "") %}
{% do cart.addLineItem(lineItem) %}
{%  do craft.app.elements.saveElement(cart) %}
```

Thus the PHP equivalent should thus be (n.b. not actually tested):

```
        // You need the cart, and actual purchasable Id of what you want to add...
        // Here was assume a product without variants...so get the default variant's id

        $cart = craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getCarts()->getCart();
        $product = \craft\commerce\elements\Product::find()->id([123])->one();
        $purchasableId = $product->getDefaultVariant()->id;

        // Create a new line item & add it to the cart
    
        $newLineItem = \craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getLineItems()->createLineItem($cart->id, $purchasableId, [], 1, 'some note');
        $cart->addLineItem($newLineItem);

        // Save the updated cart...

        Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($cart);
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out. Below is the code:

```
$theOrder = $event->sender;
$myProduct = \craft\commerce\elements\Product::find()->id([$giftProductId])->one();
if($myProduct){
    $myPurchasable = $myProduct->getDefaultVariant();
    $newOrExistingLineItem = \craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getLineItems()->resolveLineItem($theOrder->id, $myPurchasable->id, []);
    $theOrder->addLineItem($newOrExistingLineItem);
}
```